# Google Script - How to set formula to adjacent cell

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set a formula in Google Spreadsheet F2:F if E2:E has a date. If E2:E is blank, then no formula is set to F2:F.

My Code so far. Any Help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

```
function formula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/New_York", "MMMM dd, yyyy");
  var colE = sheet.getRange("E2:E");
  var colF = sheet.getRange("F2:F");

  if (colE != date){
    colF.setFormula("=round(abs(E2:E-NOW()),-1)");
  } else {
    colF.setValue("");
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it...

```
function formula(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var colE = sheet.getRange("E2:E").getValues();
  var colF = sheet.getRange("F2:F").getFormulas();
  for(var n in colE){
    if (typeof(colE[n][0])=='object'){
      colF[n][0] = "=round(abs(E"+n+":E-NOW()),-1)";
    } else {
      colF[n][0] = "";
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange('F2:F').setFormulas(colF);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Serge :) It works perfect. So i understand, what does the [0] in (typeof(colE[n][0])=='object') call or what does it reference in the spreadsheet?

Comment: getValues and getFormulas (any method that reads multiple cells range) return a 2D array (an array of arrays) even if you have only one column. The [0] is there to choose the first (and only in this case) array/column in the 2D array.  And please think about accepting the answer. thx ;-)

Comment: Thank you Serge. Makes better sense now. I will always accept your answers. You have never steered me wrong. :) Thank you!! Thank you!! Thank you!! Thank you!!